# Como identificar o versionar un archivo aspx de un proyecto web ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx

En un sitio construido con webforms, si un administrador de servidor IIS decide cambiar un archivo ASPX por uno anterior sin que esto signifique que pueda fallar, lo hace y no tengo una manera de saberlo. El caso se presenta porque un cliente es el responsable de realizar sus publicaciones, por alguna razón decidió dejar un ASPX de una versión anterior y no el nuevo, la página no presenta fallos, pero algo muy especifico que se actualizo en la ultima versión obviamente no existe.
¿Existe una forma de asegurar que el ASPX enviado corresponda o tenga una relación con la dll del ensamblado del proyecto?
Me recomiendan incluir manualmente un comentario de versión al ASPX, de tal manera que se visualice al ver el código fuente generado en el explorador, pero esto supone un riesgo al ser algo manual?
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: La manera de ir versionando al final corresponde a como decidas ir numerando lo mas recomendable es que tu agregues un valor en tu config para que sepas que version es la actual, y una manera de leer dicho config. Tu version puede ser que solo modifiques la vista o estilo y lo consideres como un cambio.

Comment: Para este tipo de cosas es muy util Git, y el numero de version en las propiedades del proyecto.

Comment: De momento dado que no encuentro un solución diferente a incluir manualmente un comentario en el maquetado (ASPX) con algo que identifique ese fuente, opte por realizar precompilación desmarcando la opción de  permitir actualizar.